# Why was ctrl+c chosen to kill a process?

Tags: command-history

I'm aware of *why* `ctrl+c` kills a program; I'm more interested in the history as to why "c" was chosen over other letters, given that it (apparently) has no semantic meaning.

If anyone knows the history behind this (and others such as `ctrl+d` for EOF), that would be awesome.

Comment: It actually was CTRL+Break and ctrl+c was added, where break is a soft terminator, and c is a hard terminator. If my memory serves me right, the break key is the same as the print screen one, but it could also be the pause. I have known why it was c. It was an abreviation of something, but it is so long ago.

Comment: I've always assumed it was for "close". unfortunately ironic, as your question is likely to be closed on opinion grounds, as non-technical "why" questions are generally impossible to solve.

Comment: @FrankThomas Of course this has a possibility of being closed. I wouldn't say it's opinion based, as it's a historical question, but that decision isn't up to me.

Comment: When a question is being closed as opinion based, it is referred to people giving an answer based on their opinion because there is no technical document to refer to to prove that they're right. Googling for CTRL-C CTRL-Break does give plenty of results, but I'm having a hard time finding anything that tells why C was chosen. So far, this answer seems to explain it the best: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/245421/ctrlc-copy-or-interrupt

Comment: Look at the _meaning_ of the low ASCII codes (see http://www.asciitable.com) - Ctrl-C was 0x03, ETX, END OF TEXT. Early keyboards used the ctrl, shift, and meta (now ALT) keys as simple "force a bit to 0 or 1" indicators, so to generate a 0x03, the 6-bit (0x40) was forced low, and the C key was pressed, because with the 6-bit free, that key would generate 0x43. 0x43 ("C") - 0x40 = 0x03, ETX.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Originally posted at Unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/245421/ctrlc-copy-or-interrupt), but I can't close vote it to that answer, so this is a copy:

> The “kill” meaning of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is very old, I
>   think even older than Unix.
>   [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-C#In_command-line_environments)
>   traces it back to TOPS-10, which would date it from the late 1960s.
>   The article explains why <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> was a reasonable
>   choice: in [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), which was
>   published in 1963, the corresponding character is ETX,
>   [end-of-text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-text_character).
>   Lacking a character meaning “stop”¹, a character meaning “this segment
>   of input is over” was a reasonable choice to mean “stop the current
>   processing”.
>
> The “copy” meaning of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> comes from Xerox
>   PARC, [the inventors of copy-paste in its modern
>   form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut,_copy,_and_paste#History) (and
>   most other fundamentals of graphical user interfaces). I don't know
>   exactly when that was, but it must have been the late 1970s. [This
>   thread on User Experience Stack
>   Exchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/86877/why-ctrl-c-for-copy-but-not-ctrl-p-for-paste)
>   discusses the choice of key bindings; C for copy makes a lot of sense.
>
> There was little reason for PARC to reject
>   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> for copy on the basis of the existing
>   meaning in TOPS-10 and Unix terminals. Operating systems and
>   applications were more diverse then, and far fewer people used
>   computers; there was no opportunity nor call for a single standard for
>   key bindings across all applications. Other uses for
>   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in popular applications include page-down
>   in [WordStar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordStar)² and
>   mode-specific command in Emacs. All of these were designed
>   independently, for applications with often different requirements,
>   running in different environments.
>
> You can configure the terminal key bindings with the [`stty`
>   command](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stty). The terminal bindings are
>   active when the terminal is in cooked mode³. For example the command
>   `stty intr ^G` sets the character that sends a SIGINT signal to
>   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.
>   The `^G` character is
>   [BEL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_character) in ASCII; when
>   sent to a terminal, it means “ring the bell”. It's the character that
>   Emacs uses for “interrupt the current operation” (rationale: the
>   application sends BEL to the user via the terminal to interrupt the
>   user; the user sends BEL to the application via the terminal to
>   interrupt the application). It doesn't have a standard meaning when
>   sent to a terminal.
>
> Most shells provide line editing features, so they set the terminal to
>   raw mode. So do full-screen text mode applications. You may need to
>   configure these applications to recognize <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>
>   instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, and some may have
>   non-configurable key bindings. So changing the interrupt character may
>   or may not be practically doable depending on which applications you
>   use.
>
> Another approach could be to configure your terminal to change the
>   byte sequence that it sends for the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
>   keychord, or make it send nothing and instead perform a copy
>   operation. You would also choose a different keychord to send
>   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (if you have a non-laptop PC keyboard,
>   you could use the out-of-the-way <kbd>Pause</kbd>/<kbd>Break</kbd>
>   key). Not all terminals can be configured in this way.
>
> ¹  <sub>Ctrl-S (XOFF) means stop, but it's addressed to the terminal,
>   not to the application.</sub>    ²  <sub>Next to
>   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> for next-line, with
>   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> for
>   previous-line and page-up; these keys were chosen due to their
>   placement on a QWERTY keyboard.</sub>    ³  <sub>Nitpick: cooked mode
>   is a set of terminal settings, including the interpretation of several
>   characters including one that sends an interrupt signal.</sub>

Comment: Nice answer, well thought out, and way more than I ever cared to know.  ;-)

Comment: Awesome answer, especially when combined with Jeff's comment. Thanks!